# Bidirectional link to another workbook

Tags: excel

I have two source workbooks (`S1`, `S2`) and a third destination workbook (`D`), which shows some data of `S1` and `S2`. So `D` has cells with external references to cells in the source workbooks. Changes in `S1`, `S2` can be synchronized to `D` because of the external references.

But it should also be possible to change the data in the source workbook from the destination workbook through these links.

For example there is the following formula in the cell `A1` of the summarizing workbook (`D`):

```
=[source1.xlsx]Table1!$E$9
```

If I enter a new value in this cell the link is replaced by the new value, but I want to store the value in the source of the link (workbook `source1.xlsx`, table `Table1`, cell `E9`).

Is there a built-in function in Excel which can update data through a link in both directions?

I haven't found such mechanism, so I'm thinking of implementing it in VBA.

Comment: No there is not a built in function, you would need VBA for that.

Comment: Thank you, I will work out a solution in VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @[bmgh1985](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2574177/bmgh1985):

> No there is not a built in function, you would need VBA for that.